# recv() on socket by dynamically allocating space

Tags: c, windows, sockets, malloc, realloc

I'm trying to get the source code of my website using c, I'm able to connect and everything but when I implement the recv() code, it only receives the last few bytes of the source code. I'd like to dynamically allocate space for the buffer to receive more using the C functions `malloc` and `realloc`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned long LEN = 200;
unsigned long cur_size = 0;

buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*LEN);
do
{
    if( status >= LEN )
    {
        cur_size += status;
        buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, cur_size);
    }
    status = recv(cSocket, buffer, LEN, 0);
    if( status == 0 )
    {
        printf("Bye\n");
    }
    else if( status > 0 )
    {
        printf("%d\n", status);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("socket error=%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        break;
    }
}while( status > 0 );
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

It still doesn't print the whole source code. How should I go about this?

Pseudocode:

```
buffer = 'len chars';
loop:
if( status >= buffer ) buffer = 'resize to status chars';
status = recv(sock, buffer, len, 0);
end loop
```

Comment: Standard warning: do **not** cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends! C is **not** C++. Also: `sizeof(char)` is _defined_ to be `1`. I.e.: it will **never** yield any other value.

Comment: You do `recv(cSocket, buffer, LEN, 0)`, i.e. every call to `recv` writes to the same buffer `buffer`, overwriting what was there before.

Comment: It is mostly is a bad idea to change your question after comments/answers had been given, as this might render the comments/answers ununderstandable. I therefor rolled back your last edit. Please add significant updates as addtion to your question.

Comment: where is status initialised and declared ?

Comment: at the beginning of the code, declared* as int status;

Comment: Uninitialized, then?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a debugger and watch the memory of your buffer, it is very easy to see what is going on.

Comment: Actually debugging code before posting on SO?  That would set a new  and dangerous precedent:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you resize the buffer in advance this needs to be reflected by its size. Which currently is **not** the case.

To fix this you could, for example, initialise `cur_size` with `LEN` by changing

```
unsigned long cur_size = 0;
```

to

```
unsigned long cur_size = LEN;
```

---

Assuming the fix above, you want to append to the buffer and not overwrite it with every call to `recv()`.

To do so change this line

```
status = recv(cSocket, buffer, LEN, 0);
```

to be

```
status = recv(cSocket, buffer + cur_size - LEN, LEN, 0);
```

---

A more straight forward approach would be to not track the size of the buffer, but the number of bytes received and just always increase the buffer by a constant size.

Also the two calls to allocate memory can be replaced by one:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
unsigned long LEN = 200;
unsigned long bytes_received = 0;
unsigned long cur_size = 0;
int status = 0;

do
{
    if (bytes_received >= cur_size)
    {
        char * tmp;
        cur_size += LEN;
        tmp = realloc(buffer, cur_size);
        if (NULL == tmp)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "realloc error=%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
          break;
        }

        buffer = tmp;
    }

    status = recv(cSocket, buffer + bytes_received, LEN, 0);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        printf("Bye\n");
    }
    else if (status > 0)
    {
      bytes_received += status;
      printf("%d\n", status);           
    }
    else /* < 0 */
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket error=%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
} while (status > 0);

printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: it throws an exception and doesn't work if I change it to that

Comment: the WSAGetLastError is 10053.ie. it's aborting the connection

Comment: @alk, still the same error code and the exception. I believe there may be a problem where I'm reallocating memory.

Comment: @Hawk: Yes I see, fixed my proposals to be in sync.

Comment: @Hawk: You see the issue, and understand what is going on?

Comment: @Hawk: It would help if you would trace the code inside a debugger.

Comment: @alk, I've added some pseudocode of what I expect the reallocation to do, I hope that clarifies the question

Comment: @Hawk When calling `recv()` the buffer needs to be **larger**, as the amount of data **already received**. And to append to the end of the buffer it does **not** make sense to always pass `buffer` to `recv()` as it **always** just points to the **beginning** of the buffer.

Comment: @Hawk - you seem to be ignoring all suggestions that you run the code under a debugger.  Why is that?

Comment: I don't know how to run them under a debugger, and the issue is how to allocate memory on the fly. The allocation happens well and good but writing to the buffer becomes an issue.

Comment: In the VC IDE choose debug but run, then use the F10 key. @Hawk

Comment: @alk, i'm using dev c++

Comment: @Hawk: Then just RTFM. Without using the debugger you are more or less lost.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bit of research, I came across this website and finally found what I was looking for.

[Binary tides](http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-recv-socket-function-in-c/)

Although it uses linux's `fcntl`, the windows equivalent is `ioctlsocket` which is used to set the socket's non-blocking mode.

To see the exact function, visit the website. I modified the version and set my socket to blocking mode.

```
int total_recv(SOCKET s)
{
    int size_recv = 0, total_size = 0, block = 00;
    char chunk[BUFLEN];

    ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, (unsigned long*)&block); // set mode to block
    // not necessary but clarification of function, mode is block by
    // default

    while( 1 )
    {
        memset(chunk, 0, BUFLEN);
        if( ( size_recv = recv(s, chunk, BUFLEN, 0) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            printf("Error receiving\n");
        }
        else if( size_recv == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            total_size += size_recv;

            // i used file since console wouldn't show full source code
            FILE *fp = NULL;
            fp = fopen("source.txt", "a");
            fprintf(fp, chunk);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    return total_size;
}
```

Comment: Sockets are blocking by default so you don't need the ioctlsocket call. Your own solution deviates from the requirements you stated in the opening post : 'I'd like to dynamically allocate space for the buffer to receive more using the C functions malloc and realloc.' you are opening a file and appending all the time. This is not the best solution. Open the file once and close it when done.

Comment: If it was your intention to write the data to a file to begin with, then the code you provided above is better than what you started with. But if I were you I would give alk some more credit and accept his answer.

Comment: Bottom line is you changed your mind as to the dynamically allocating space part. You are no longer doing that. Changing your mind is not a problem of course, if the design is better by all means do.

Comment: I tried using his modifications but changing the code to his solution threw an exception because the socket kept aborting the connection.

Comment: He is giving advice, you are supposed to keep thinking for yourself too. But if you don't even know how to use a debugger, you should not be playing around with sockets to begin with. It is advanced material and it is way over your head.